# What is the difference between apache 2.4 (CentOS) and apache 2.4 (Red Hat)?

Tags: php, apache, centos, redhat, php-7.1

I want to use rh-php71 from Red Hat which is built against apache 2.4 (Red Hat) and make it work with apache 2.4 (CentOS). Is this possible to work with stability?

Answer (score 0):

There should not be any difference since CentOS = RHEL.

The [CentOS](https://www.centos.org/about/) Linux distribution is a stable, predictable, manageable and reproducible platform derived from the sources of Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL).

Comment: By default, this option doesn't work. In order to make it work, I created 3 symlinks: 

ln -s /opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/conf.d/rh-php71-php.conf /etc/httpd/conf.d/

ln -s /opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/15-rh-php71-php.conf /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/
ln -s /opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/modules/librh-php71-php7.so /etc/httpd/modules/